# On-the-fly SMB shares conf to quickly share files

Tags: permissions, samba, smb, shared-folders

I want to use samba to quickly and easily share files on occasions.
I set up a smbuser to which I forbid login with

```
chsh -s /bin/false smbuser
```

I give the smbuser's password to people and I have my home dir with another username I keep safe.

Let's suppose I have this folder `/home/steve/pictures/vacation/...` I want to share.

With a quick `chown steve:smbuser vacation` I can set the following permissions

```
drwxr----- 35 steve smbuser  4096 Mar 28 18:58  vacation
```

then I set this service on my smb.conf

```
[shared]
        comment = Used to share files quickly. Just change path down here
        path = /home/steve/pictures/vacation
        browsable = yes
        read only = yes
        create mask = 0700
        directory mask = 0700
        valid user = smbuser
```

with this configuration I cannot connect to this share.

If I

```
chmod -R 777 /home/steve
```

I can connect, but this is not the way.

How can I configure this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to go for `usershare` command

Beside my `/home/steve` I set up a `/home/public` directory to which I gave 777 permission and I'm using it to receive files.

When I need to share my files with someone other I can quickly give

```
chgrp smbuser /home/steve/share
chmod g+r -R /home/steve/share
```

so that my `smbuser` can access it

Then I create my share with the command

```
net usershare add public /home/public/ . S-1-1-0:F
```

Note the "F" in the end to give "full access" at share DOS level

For more info reference: man smb.conf - Usershares section

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/474830/how-does-the-samba-usershare-acl-parameter-work) helped a lot as well